# Rigid Body Simulation Problem Ball Is Not Entering The Bowl, stopping In Air

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

[image]

I am trying to make this ball enter the bowl but it is stopping midway, like there is an invisible surface.

Comment: nvr mind got it

Comment: yes but please give the answer in case someone else is looking for it, actually I guess you need to choose Physics > Rigid Body Collisions > Shape > Mesh

Comment: Using all caps is considered rude